# How do I query MongoDB's ISODate field using Java querybuilder

Tags: java, mongodb, isodate

I would like to do a query based on a MongoDB ISODate field.
However, I'm not sure how to serialize a Java Date
object into the correct ISODate object, which can then be 
used with QueryBuilder. A little example code would be greatly
appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization of a Date object to the appropriate representation in JSON ({$date:

```
builder.greaterThan(new Date())
```

works just fine. Be wary of timezones though.

Comment: I couldn't get expected result because of another bug. The date serialization part works well actually. In any case, thanks for your quick and insightful reply! :)